# printing delimiters in c language

Tags: c

I am using `strtok()`.But i want to print corresponding delimiters also as we do using `StringTokenizer` in Java.Is there any function which provides this functionality(printing delimiters) ?

Comment: Can you explain further and give sample input and output?

Comment: Delimiters corresponding to what?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to read file,if i find a specific word i should replace it with "XYZ". File content should not be altered. That is why i need to get delimiters also before writing content back to the file.

Comment: "abc,123.qwerty lop." Assume this is file content.using strtok i will get abc what about "," ?

Comment: I am trying to emulate tr command in unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on OP's comments, tokenization is not what is actually desired. You want to use `strstr()`, not `strtok()`. That will tell you if the string is present, and then you can use `strcpy()` and `strcat()` as appropriate.

Please note, the "n" versions of these methods, i.e. `strncpy` and `strncat`, are safer -- less likely to crash due to buffer overrun.

Comment: Yes ! it seems like so . I will refer to all str***() functions to get required functionality .

Comment: strstr won't help you much, unless you have only one delimiter, in which case you may as well use strchr.  strstr finds one entire string within another, rather than a character from a *set* within another.

Comment: @Mud, there are no delimiters. OP does not want to tokenize. See comments on the question.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to print corresponding delimiters also as we do using StringTokenizer in Java

Java's StringTokenizer *doesn't* return delimeters.

In any case, there is no such function in C. You'll have to write one (using strchr, etc.)

Comment: It does return delimiters . see the third parameter. pass true as a parameter.you will get it.

Comment: There are three versions of StringTokenizers in java.

Answer (score 0):

How about using glib?
It seems 
http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.26/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strsplit

is exactly what you're looking for.